# How can I get a "CMake" build to take an arbitrary, user-specified, file as input?

Tags: cmake

I want to be able to do something like:

```
C:\> build.cmd MyFile.in
```

And have `build.cmd` invoke a CMake build system, using `MyFile.in` as input.  This would ideally not have to regenerate the CMake cache every time, but just run the existing cache on the specified file.

I might then also want to invoke this build on other files, to produce other outputs:

```
C:\> build.cmd OtherFile.in
```

Does that make sense?  I.e. I want CMake to be runnable almost like a command line tool.

Comment: What would `MyFile.in` look like?  Is it still a `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: No.  Some arbitrary data I want to process using a CMake build system.  MyFile.in --> MyFile.out.

Comment: *"some data I want to process using a cmake build system"*. We cannot really provide a reasonable answer unless we know how it's used. The only "input" you pass to a cmake build systems in general are the `CMakeLists.txt` file and some cache variables, which really doesn't explain how you expect `MyFile.in` to influence the project created...

Comment: Imagine I have 137 different tools I need to run in a variety of sequences, producing a variety of outputs, all of them interdependent in a directed acyclic manner.  The "file" that is used as the first input to this cascade is `MyFile.in`, or it may be `OtherFile.in`, or any number of arbitrary user-defined files.  What I want to do is define the targets and dependencies of those 137 build steps using CMake, in such a way that they can operate on arbitrary input but retain the nice characteristics of CMake's build system.  Make sense?

Comment: You can probably get away with a launcher script and an environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Just introduce a cache variable...

```
set(MY_FILE "" CACHE FILEPATH "Input file")
if (NOT MY_FILE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Must supply a file as input.")
endif ()
```

Then you can just pass a file path to an existing CMake build tree like so:

```
$ cmake -B /path/to/build -DMY_FILE:FILEPATH=MyFile.in
```

Comment: I think this may work, thank you.  What I observe is that the CMake build tree does not need to be fully regenerated each time, but I *do* need to issue the command to regenerate it.  Not ideal, but perhaps workable.